# normalized mutual information implantation in java for community detection in graph range is not between 0 and 1

Tags: java, machine-learning, bayesian, information-theory

I write a program for calculating normalized mutual information for evaluate community detection. But I get values above 1 for nmi. Normally it should be between 0 and 1. I implement formula in http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html

What is wrong with my code?

here is my code:

```
    public void calNmi(int size, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> realcom, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> foundcom){

    List<Double> hf = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> hr = new ArrayList<>();
    double I = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> found : foundcom.entrySet()) {
        int comSize = found.getValue().size();
        double p = (double) comSize/size;
        hf.add( -p * (Math.log(p)/Math.log(2)));
     }


    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> real : realcom.entrySet()) {
        int comSize = real.getValue().size();
        double p = (double) comSize/size;
        hr.add(-p * (Math.log(p)/Math.log(2)));
    }

    int i =0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> real : realcom.entrySet()) {
        if(i%100 == 0){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        List<Integer> rCom = real.getValue();
        double pr = (double) rCom.size()/size;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> found : foundcom.entrySet()) {
            List<Integer> fCom = found.getValue();
            double pf = (double) fCom.size()/size;
            int intersect = foundIntersect(rCom, fCom);
            if(intersect != 0) {
                double p = (double) intersect / size;
                I += p * (Math.log(p / (pr * pf))) / Math.log(2);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    double sumH  = 0;
    for (Double sumh : hr) {
        sumH += sumh;
    }
    double sumF = 0;
    for (Double sumf : hf) {
        sumF += sumf;
    }
    System.out.println("I = " + I + " hf = "+ sumF + " hr " + sumH);
    double nmi = (2 * I)/(sumF + sumH);
    System.out.println("nmi = " + nmi);

}

private int foundIntersect(List<Integer> rCom, List<Integer> fCom) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer r : rCom) {
        if(fCom.contains(r)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I see a couple of incongruent ideas in the code, but to tell which one is the problem and which one is what you are intending I need a little more information. specifically, please update your question to tell me what realcom  and foundcom are actually representing. from your code it looks like they might be maps of lists which represent discretized signals that are to be compared, but your code is wrong for that in some places and right for it in others. Alternatively they could be histograms of datasets, but then I wouldn't expect the list to be embedded within a map.